# SmsRetrieverClient.startSmsUserConsent () How to pass different sender numbers as parameter?

Tags: java

SmsRetrieverClient.startSmsUserConsent (senderPhoneNumber /* or null */)

This senderPhoneNumber is the number I know I will be receiving OTP from. My question is if I pass null, it can extract OTP from any number as documentation says (pass null so that it will consider any number would be allowed.). How will I know that my sender is correct? What happens if I receive two OTPs?

If this is not possible can I somehow pass two sender numbers that I am sure that either would be sending my OTP?

Anyone have any knowledge regarding this, please let know.

Comment: when Ever I use the sender number my SmsRetrieverClient  does not work how did you do that.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did my research and writing my answer with my best. Coming to your questions

> 1. What happens if I receive two OTPs?

The answer to this question is you will not receive two messages in most of the cases which contain an OTP within a span of 5 minutes.

Even though let's consider a worse situation. Suppose you receive 2 SMS containing OTP back to back in that case SMS user consent API will only show the consent for the first received SMS (Assuming you have mentioned `null` as sender phone number).

So basically what happens is the user consent api will stop listning for sms once it detects and show a consent.

> 2. If this is not possible can I somehow pass two sender numbers that I
>    am sure that either would be sending my OTP?

Answer : Yes you can. if you know the senders possible names i.e say **`AD-Something, BC-Something, CC-Something`** then you can register the listners for all 3 of them one by one like this

```
 val task1 = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("AD-Something")
 val task2 = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("CC-Something")
 val task3 = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("BC-Something")
```

once you declare like this your device will listen for all of those. Make sure you also check for a callback on these to know whether they are successful or not

> How do I know these?

There is no official source/documentation for this. (I looked for the documentation but I didn't find any mentions regarding this) Then I tried it for myself and found it.

Honestly, I have a feeling like this question is just another version of pre-mature optimization at this time

Thank you.

Comment: I will run this and let you know if adding listeners work. Thank you for digging up though!

Comment: Yeah ... let me know once

Comment: How about if the first two characters of my sender are dynamic? Like “Something” remains same but AD, BC, CC keeps changing and I don’t know those characters?

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I looked into android documents but there is no mention of it. There are questions on SO which are still unanswered regarding this topic